# How can I pass arguments in a function?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have this array of entities:

```
entitiesArr.push(
{ 
    id: "1234",
    entityName: "ASDF",
    tasktype: "Lorem lorem?", 
    isYesNo: true
});
```

Where Im trying to do something like

```
{{#each entities}}

    <div>
        {{tasktype}}

        {{#if isYesNo}}
            <button type="button" onclick="Button_Click({{{entityName}}})">!</button>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

However... using `{{{entityName}}}` breaks it, using `{{{id}}}` works like a charm. My goal is to pass in two parameters: `function Button_Click(id, name)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a string to a method, you need to wrap it in quotes for it to work.

```
<button type="button" onclick="Button_Click('{{{entityName}}}')">!</button>
```

So, passing both in looks like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="Button_Click({{id}},'{{entityName}}')">!</button>
```